# Zend_Form equivalent for ruby / rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, zend-form

Does anyone know if it there exist any Ruby or rails equivalent of zend_form?

I'm asking because I'm porting a project that I made in PHP with zend framework over to rails. This an event registration/form builder which basically means I need to generate forms from fields in a database. Zend_Form makes creating forms programmaticly very easy with validation and the works. Now I need to make this in rails but I can't see how it can be done any other way than making it all from scratch.
Any ideas on the matter is very much appreciated. :)

If there's nothing like zend_form for rails/ruby is anybody interested in making it with me? I'm very new to rails and Ruby so i could very much need the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) or [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) isn't enough? Add to this partials and you have similar tool that looks much better and is MVC.

Comment: It might be enough. I'm using simple_form already for all other forms. I'm sure I could manage to generate a form, but how would the validation then be done? The form would be generated is not tied to a model with validations like it normally is. The validation needs to be generated from the information about the form fields thats stored in the database. Hmm. Maybe I could make another model that added validations dynamically (if thats possible?). Or it might be logical to actually do that in the Reply model?

Comment: This gave me something to think about. Thanks for the response! I'll be back if my thinking doesn't pan out. :P

Comment: Validations you can make in model, and if it is needed then you can specify them to run only on save or update, so I'm still don't see what do you want to achieve with something like Zend_Form what is IMHO ugly solution cause Controller shouldn't bother about View, neither Model.

Comment: Yeah I think it should work out pretty fine without something like Zend_Form. But the whole point with Zend_Form is that the whole thing is defined in a  class so I don't see how that is ugly. Am I not understanding something?

Comment: As can I see you don't understand MVC style and that is the problem. Model only has data, controller only parse data, view only show data. That what you trying to achieve is controller that generate view.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand MVC. No that is not what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to create a form with validations programmaticly. It is not possible as far as I have seen.
Using simple_form or formtastic doen not fix my problem. My problem is dynamicly creating a model to render the form from. I have tried severeal thing but it does not seem doable with only an activerecord model.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your problem is simple and there are many solutions. I recommend honoring MVC by creating an (ActiveRecord) Model to represent your form data. Add the Formtastic gem to your project, and your view can be (basically) as simple as one line: `f.inputs` will generate the appropriate form inputs for every field on your model. The form will honor the validations declared in your model, and errors will be displayed in-line automatically. Again, I believe you'll find that a solution is dramatically simpler in Rails.  Best of luck. https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic